# I have a GreetingServer.java (using sockets). Want to make a JFrame for it

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I have made a java program using sockets for a `GreetingServer` which waits for clients to connect. It works. The thing is I want to make a `JFrame` for it, having a Start Server button, for example, which starts the server. Having `GreetingServer.java` and `GreetingServerUI.java` (which is the `JFrame` having the button), how can I combine these 2 java files in a way that my button uses method from `GreetingServer.java` to start my server?
This is just an example for me to start a bigger project, but I don't know this basic stuff. Thank you!

I would put my file here, but I don't know how.
EDIT:

GreetingServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
{
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   serverSocket.setSoTimeout(60000);
}

public void run()
{
  while(true)
  {
     try
     {
        System.out.println("Se asteapta un client pe portul " +
        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Conectarea cu "
              + server.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " s-a facut.");
        DataInputStream in =
              new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        DataOutputStream out =
             new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Multumim ca v-ati conectat la "
          + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nPa pa!");
        server.close();
     }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
     {
        System.out.println("Timpul socketului s-a terminat!");
        break;
     }catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
     }
  }
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  int port = 9000;
  try
  {
     Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
     t.start();
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

And here is the GreetingServerUI.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServerUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form GreetingServerUI
 */
public GreetingServerUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("Start Server");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new     javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(162, 162, 162)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(132, 132, 132)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(145, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GreetingServerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GreetingServerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GreetingServerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GreetingServerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GreetingServerUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: edit your question and please add code of GreetingsServer.java and GreeetingServerUI.java

Comment: *"but I don't know this basic stuff."*  This is [OOP 101](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) which should be figured out long before attempting a GUI..  VTC as 'too broad'.

Comment: Hi @Lucky , I added the code for both java files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I'm getting you correctly you are pretty much asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569725/1793718), you have to use the [`actionPerformed`](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener) method of the JButton class. In your case you should first import the `GreetingServer.java` class in your `GreetingServerUI.java` using the import statement,

```
import GreetingServer.java  //if both are in same package
```

Then in your `GreetingServerUI`'s  *`jButton1ActionPerformed`*  method

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException{                                         
      //create a GreetingServer object and call the method you want in the
      //GreetingServer.java using dot(.) operator like for example,
      GreetingServer gServer = new GreetingServer(9000);
      gServer.run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did what you said.
My both java files are in the same package named greetingserver and I have the "package greetingserver;" line in both java files, but I get the error: " error: package GreetingServer does not exist
import GreetingServer.java;"

Comment: I made a class for GreetingServer.java in the same package and then I imported it
     import greetingserver.GreetingServer;
but I receive " error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      GreetingServer gServer = new GreetingServer(9000); "

Comment: Can you, please, help me a little more? Now I want to use instead of `System.out.println(" e.g. Connection made")`  the option to write those messages in a jTextArea in the jFrame. But I don't know how to do this either, what and where to import to be able to change System.out.println() with jTextArea1.append().

Comment: @VictorasMarcu updated the answer..for the other thing you should probably ask a new question..if you find my solution working you can either accept the answer or upvote it..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I think I solved it. When I press the JButton, my server starts.
My JButton's actionPerformed looks like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //create a GreetingServer object and call the method you want in the
  //GreetingServer.java using dot(.) operator like for example,
    int port=9000;
    try
    {
     Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
     t.start();
    }catch(IOException e)
    { 
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```