# How do I use a JButton to call a method if clicked

Tags: java

I made getButtons(); method to create buttons and reduce unnecessary lines if I did each button seperately. Then I used in actionPerformed getText(); so whenever I click one of these 3 buttons it gives me it's text (if I click button 1, it prints out 1). What I intend to do now is I want to use each button for seperate things, for example I want to call out with button "1" method getMath(); while other 2 buttons can do other things, like call different methods.

I'm not sure how to do it, so I am here to ask help. Thank you.

```
    void getMath() {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 5;
        System.out.println(x + y);
    }

    void getButtons() {
        String[] buttons = { "1", "2", "3" };
        int height = 250;
        int gap = 65;
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            JButton gameButtons = new JButton(buttons[i]);
            gameButtons.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 19));
            gameButtons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            gameButtons.setBounds(394, 50 + (height + gap * i), 150, 40);
            gameButtons.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            gameButtons.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        gameButtons.addActionListener(this);
            frame.add(gameButtons);
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
                
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Call Method via JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569700/java-call-method-via-jbutton)

Answer (score 0):

right now, you are using the same EventListener for all your Buttons.
In order to achieve a different handling per button, you have to implement different actionPerformed events.

Therefor, I suggest you to not create the Buttons inside a loop, but rather create them separately. You know, that you will have 3 Buttons, so no need to loop.
With lambdas this should roughly look like

```
gameButton1.addActionListener(e->method1(e));
gameButton2.addActionListener(e->method2(e));
gameButton3.addActionListener(e->method3(e));
```

with having a signature

```
void method1(ActionEvent e)
```

Comment: I made these 3 buttons just for the test so I can work when I'll need to make more than 3 buttons and won't need 200 lines of code to make each button seperately but use a loop similar to this to do it with something like 50 lines. I understand what you are suggesting me but here I want to realize the seperate use of each button from a loop. All I know is that it is possible but it is a little above my programming knowledge and confuses me.

Comment: well, at some point you have to differentiate between the buttons to determine which action to trigger. you could also write a common actionPerformed method and do a switch statement inside. if you want to have 200 different actions with each having a different logic, then it will be difficult to do that without having 200 different handlers